# CSS relative absolute position

Tags: css, position, css-position

I just have a container div-element that contains two div-elements that should appear at the same level on both sides of the container-div. The following solution does not work:

```
<div id="result" >
    <div class="right">Update</div>
    <div class="left">delete</div>
</div>
```

stylesheet follows:

```
div.left{
position:absolute;
left: 5px;
top:0px;
color: green;
border-style:solid;
border-color: green;
}
div.right{
position:absolute;
right: 2px;
top:0px;
color: red;
border-style:solid;
border-color: red;
}
#result{
position:relative;
width:100%;
border-style:solid;
border-color: blue;
}
```

The blue margin from the container-div does not contains the the other two divs and appears on top of the other two containers.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: http://www.mikepadgett.com/technology/technical/alternative-to-the-pie-clearfix-hack/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have put position which is not needed basically.
see below answer

html here

```
<div id="result" >
<div class="right">Update</div>
<div class="left">delete</div>
</div>
```

css here

```
div.left{
left: 5px;
top:0px;
color: green;
border-style:solid;
border-color: green;
float:left;
}
div.right{
right: 2px;
top:0px;
color: red;
border-style:solid;
border-color: red;
float:right;
}
#result{
width:100%;
border-style:solid;
border-color: blue;
float:left;

}
```

live example here.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waKrH

Comment: becuase if container div contains div which are having float.
then outer div will not expand and inner div will be shown out side of container div.

try to delete float from container div in codepen example. you will see result.

Comment: yes thanks for guiding me.
but for future html code. if we have mode div inside container div and if we use clear both. then it will mess other div and that other div will be visible in rows other then side by side.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally the .left and .right divs would be [floated](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxT4X/1/):

```
div.left{
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    color: green;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color: green;
}

div.right{
    float: right;
    margin: 5px;
    color: red;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color: red;
}
```

Comment: It does not work unless you float the container-div too ... don't ask me why because I am puzzled

Comment: You need a clear fix (in my jsfiddle it's the empty div). More info: http://jonrohan.me/guide/css/clear-fixes/

Answer (score 0):

What you could try is float:left to both of the elements your trying to put side by side, that should push-force them, see if it works and let me know.

Comment: The problem is that the container-div does not envolves the other two if I just float them

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uzgL9/)?

Better way is to change the apsolute into relative,with floating.
And if you use floating, dont forget to add `overflow:hidden;` to the parent container.